# Настройка кодировки апача

Tags: apache, кодировка, apache2

Хочу настроить кодировку в апаче, только не совсем понимаю как.

Сейчас у меня прописан тег `<meta >` в заголовке `html` странички. Где посмотреть, какая кодировка в данный момент выставлена в апаче? Как ее правильно изменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить можно в .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```